# How to find the derivative of the following matrix?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Let $V$ be $n$ by $m$ matrix and let $x$ be $m$ by $1$ vector, i.e.,
$$V = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
V_{11}&V_{12}&\cdots&V_{1m}\\
V_{21}&V_{22}&\cdots&V_{2m}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
V_{n1}&V_{n2}&\cdots&V_{nm}\\
\end{array}\right] \qquad \text{and}\qquad x=\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_m\end{array}\right].$$

I want to know of $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}(Vx)$.

---

I know that the derivative of a matrix $M$ with respect to a vector $x$ is defined by $$\frac{d}{dx}(M)=\left[\begin{array}{c} \displaystyle\frac{dM}{dx_1}\\\displaystyle\frac{dM}{dx_2}\\\vdots\\\displaystyle\frac{dM}{dx_m}\end{array}\right].$$

---

So, let me solve $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}(Vx)=\frac{d}{dx}(M)$ using
$$
M = Vx = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
V_{11}x_1+V_{12}x_2+\cdots+V_{1m}x_m\\
V_{21}x_1+V_{22}x_2+\cdots+V_{2m}x_m\\
\vdots\\
V_{n1}x_1+V_{n2}x_2+\cdots+V_{nm}x_m\\
\end{array}\right].
$$

As the above, $M$ is $n$ by $1$ matrix (=vector).

Then, how can I find $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}(M)$? Does it become $nm$ by $1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Derivatives_with_vectors, your derivative must be an $n\times m$ matrix, which will happen to be $V$ in this case

Comment: I've learned that, for a row vector $x=(x_1, \cdots, x_m)$, $\displaystyle\frac{dM}{dx}=\left[\frac{dM}{dx_1}~~\frac{dM}{dx_2}~~\cdots~~ \frac{dM}{dx_m}\right]$, while, for a column vector $x=(x_1, \cdots, x_m)'$, where $'$ is the transpose mark, $\displaystyle\frac{dM}{dx}=\left[\frac{dM}{dx_1}~~\frac{dM}{dx_2}~~\cdots~~ \frac{dM}{dx_m}\right]'$. However, in Wikipedia you linked, for a column vector $x$, they wrote $\displaystyle\frac{dM}{dx}=\left[\frac{dM}{dx_1}~~\frac{dM}{dx_2}~~\cdots~~ \frac{dM}{dx_m}\right].$ What is the true?

Comment: @Danny_Kim: The Wikipedia makes sense. $dM$ is the same shape as $M$, $dx$ is the same shape as $x$. Now try to multiply $\frac{dM}{dx}$ with $dx$ and see if you get $dM$